# Cannot delete table

Tags: google-bigquery

I don't seem to be able to delete my table 387047224813. API calls fail with *Undefined error*, and when I try through the console it doesn't complain, but it doesn't delete the table either.

How can I fix this problem?

To confirm, I'm using the following API code from the API documenation, which works fine with any other table, just not with this one:

```
# Delete a table
def deleteTable(service, projectId, datasetId, tableId):
  try:
    service.tables().delete(projectId=projectId, datasetId=datasetId, tableId=tableId).execute()

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ("The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run the application to re-authorize")

  except Exception as err:
    print 'Undefined error' % err

  except:
    print "\nWARNING: Table [" + tableId + "] doesn't exist!\n"
```

I get the error *Undefined error*, with no explanation

The fact that the Delete Table command in the web console doesn't delete the table either makes me think that there may be a problem at [BigQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) with this specific table.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO! Please post some code, or whatever it is you're doing, to clarify your question. As it stands, it's just guesswork and we prefer being able to give answers based on fact. =)

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using the API code example provided in the API documentation to delete a table, which works fine with any other table. Also I have tried through the console option, by clicking on the Delete table option.

Comment: Hi Juan:

Are you still seeing this issue with that single table?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I am. In fact I created a second table using the output of the same select and I cannot delete this one either. I have given the proper details of the tables below in the answer to Jordan. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery table ids have three parts -- project id, dataset id, and table id. The value you gave '387047224813' is a project id .. but in order to delete a table, you need to specify a dataset and table id as well. If you are specifying the dataset and table id, can you let us now which ones they are?

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I'm having problems to delete two tables, both of them created as a result of  the same query. The tables are: 387047224813:pos_dw_api.handParticipant and 387047224813:pos_dw_api.handParticipant2.

Comment: You've hit an internal bug in bigQuery. I'm working on a fix.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, let me know when you would like me to try again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this, it should now be fixed. (both the problem that you were able to get a table into a bad state and that delete didn't work on the table). Please try again and let us know if you have any further problems.

Comment: Hi Jordan, I have just tried with the 4 tables I now have with this problem, which are: handParticipant, handParticipant2, handParticipant3 and handParticipant4. I was unable to delete any of them via the web console or API call. Thanks.

Comment: I can see the deletion failures in our logs, but it looks like the most recent one was 9:59 AM PST yesterday, the release where this was fixed was at 10:45 AM PST. Any chance you can try again?

Comment: Hi Jordan, I have tried again right now (Fri 17 Aug 2012 11:50:48 BST) on all these four tables, both through the web console and from the API, with no luck. Also checked that other tables work fine, I've just been recreating some today without issues. Thanks

Comment: I know I've said this before, but this time it really is fixed. Please let us know if you have any further problems.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I have tested this and I can confirm that the issue is fixed. I deleted the 4 tables in trouble, some via console and some via API without issues. Thanks